# How to insert a mindmap with TiKZ in a A4paper

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, mindmaps

I need to create a mindmap by LaTex.
After rading the manual, I made the mindmap below as changing an example.

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mindmap,
    grow cyclic, text width=4cm, align=flush center,
    every node/.style={concept},
    concept color=orange!40,
    %root/.style= {concept color=black!40,font=\large\bfseries,text width=12em},
    level 1/.style={level distance=8cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45},
    level 3/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45}]]

\node [root concept] {\textbf{Root concept}}
   child [concept color=blue!30] { node {Classification}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
    }
    child [concept color=green!30] { node {One concept}
        child [concept color=green!40]{ node {description \\ of concept 1}}
       % child { node {B}}
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!30] { node {Second \\ concept}
        child { node {Environment}}
        child { node {concept two}}
        child [concept color=red!40] { node {concept \\ three}
                child { node {Description of child concept one}}  
                child { node {Description of child concept two}}
                child { node {Description of child concept three}}      
        }
    }
    child [concept color=teal!40]  { node {Other concept}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {...}}
        child { node {...}}
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I resize the mindmap in order to insert this in a A4 document? I tried to insert the mindmap changing the document class the design comes out from the sheet.
2. I would like the circle relative to the root concept was bigger than the other. How can I do?

Thanks in advance for you collaboration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fit it in a A4 page, you can enclose the `tikzpicture` with

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    *code here*
}
```

For the node size, adding `scale=2` does the trick. I also added a couple more things, for example enclosing the `tikzpicture` in a figure environment, so you can apply a caption.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mindmap,
    grow cyclic, text width=4cm, align=flush center,
    every node/.style={concept},
    concept color=orange!40,
    %root/.style= {concept color=black!40,font=\large\bfseries,text width=12em},
    level 1/.style={level distance=8cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45},
    level 3/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45}]]

\node [root concept, scale=2] {\textbf{Root concept}}
   child [concept color=blue!30] { node {Classification}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
    }
    child [concept color=green!30] { node {One concept}
        child [concept color=green!40]{ node {description \\ of concept 1}}
       % child { node {B}}
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!30] { node {Second \\ concept}
        child { node {Environment}}
        child { node {concept two}}
        child [concept color=red!40] { node {concept \\ three}
                child { node {Description of child concept one}}  
                child { node {Description of child concept two}}
                child { node {Description of child concept three}}      
        }
    }
    child [concept color=teal!40]  { node {Other concept}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {...}}
        child { node {...}}
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```